# Spring Boot Batch dynamic multiple dataSource with JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, datasource

Project based on Spring boot and batch. I need to use h2 database for storing metadata for spring batch tables and postgre for Spring JPA(Used by ItemWriter).

I have defined two separate properties in properties file.

```
postgres.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://urlxxx
postgres.datasource.username=xxx
postgres.datasource.password=yyy

batch.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
batch.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
batch.datasource.username=xxx2
batch.datasource.password=yyy2
```

Now, In @configuration file in order to link batch datasource I defined,

```
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="batch.datasource")
@Bean(name="dataSourceBatch")
public DataSource firstDataSource() {
    DataSource ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    return ds;
}

@Bean
  BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceBatch") DataSource dataSource){
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
  }
```

However, I didn't used another jpa(postgre) db configuration anywhere else,(planning to link it with JPA).

When I am trying to run the project, i am getting below exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceBatch': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$189.0000000010E4E030.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:408) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$189.0000000010E4E030.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
```

What the issue? I didnt declare any other datasource so  that spring boot start creating one. Also, How can I decalre the postgre datasource such that it can be used by jpa for interation with DB.

Sorry, if this question sound very basic, I am noob in spring.

Added batchconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfig {
        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

     
        @Bean
        ItemReader<ABC> reader() {
            return new LocationReader();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        @Bean
        ItemProcessor<ABC,ABC> moviesItemProcessor() {
            return new LocationProcessor();
        }

        @Bean
        ItemWriter<ABC> Writer(){

            return new LocationWriter();
            
        }


        @Bean
        public Step step1(ItemReader<ABC> reader,
                            ItemProcessor<ABC,ABC> processor,
                            ItemWriter<ABC> writer) throws Exception {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .<ABC, ABC>chunk(10)
                    .reader(reader)
                    .processor(processor)
                    .writer(writer).allowStartIfComplete(true)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Job job(Step step1) throws Exception {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                    .start(step1(reader(), moviesItemProcessor(), Writer()))
                    .build();
        }
        
        
        
        
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="batch.datasource")
        @Bean(name="dataSourceBatch")
        public DataSource firstDataSource() {
            DataSource ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
            return ds;
        }
       
          @Bean
          BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceBatch") DataSource dataSource){
            return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
          }

        
//
//      @Bean
//      public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
//          final JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
//          factory.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.H2.getProductName());
//          factory.setDataSource(firstDataSource());
//          return factory.getObject();
//      }
//
//      @Bean
//      public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
//          final SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
//          launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
//          return launcher;
//      }
        

        @Autowired
        JobLauncher jol;

        
        @Autowired
        Job job;
         
        
        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void perform() throws Exception 
        {
            JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .toJobParameters();
            jol.run(job, params);
        }

}
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Added above

Answer (score 2):

> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceBatch': Requested bean is currently in creation

You are injecting the data source (which is being created) in the batch configurer here:

```
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="batch.datasource")
@Bean(name="dataSourceBatch")
public DataSource firstDataSource() {
   DataSource ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   return ds;
}

@Bean
BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceBatch") DataSource dataSource){
   return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
}
```

Try to move data source configuration in another class:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

   @Primary
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="batch.datasource")
   @Bean(name="dataSourceBatch")
   public DataSource firstDataSource() {
      DataSource ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      return ds;
   }

}
```

Then import it in your batch configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class})
public class BatchConfig {

   private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
   private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

   public BatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
       this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
       this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
   }


   @Bean
   BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceBatch") DataSource dataSource){
      return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
   }

   // the rest of you config

}
```

Note also how I removed field injection of `jobBuilderFactory` and `stepBuilderFactory` and replaced it with constructor injection.